# Show next "DateInterval" value depending on actual time

Tags: php, datetime

I use a "DateInterval" with an interval of 3 hours to get all the dates between a start and end time. The result looks like that:

`15:00 | 18:00 | 21:00 | 00:00 | 03:00  (and so on...)`

Now I'm searching a solution that only the next "DateInterval" value gets shown (depending on the actual time), and not all of them.

**Example:** if the actual time is `19:29` the shown result should be `21:00`.

My code so far:

```
$start = new DateTime('2022-12-18 15:00:00');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('3 hours');
$end = new DateTime('2022-12-31 15:00:00');

$occurrences = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($occurrences as $occurrence) {

    echo $occurrence->format('H:i') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: If the current time is before `$occurrence`, print `$occurrence` and break out of the loop.

Comment: Do you need a period or a particular `DateTime` after all?

Comment: @Jared I need a DateTime (only the time, not the date).

Comment: The DateTime extension Dt (github.com/jspit-de/Dt) has its own methods for such tasks: $date = Dt::create('Now')->next('3 Hours');

Comment: Carbon (https://carbon.nesbot.com/) also has a method for this: ->floorUnit('hour',3);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No need to iterate through the period. Just manipulate current hour number.
This probably might be reworked with plain unix timestamps for even simplier code:

```
<?php

// This is just for test, in the code below
// should be replaced with plain `(new DateTime)`
$now = new DateTime('2022-12-18 19:29:00');

// Set the next fraction-3 hour
$result = ( new DateTime )
    ->setTime(
        // Divide current hour by 3, take integer part,
        // add one, multiply by 3, take 24 modulo 
        // (to get '0' instead of '24' and '3' instead of '27')
        (((int)($now->format('H') / 3) + 1 ) * 3) % 24,
        0
    );

// The result
// Note, the date is current here
print $result->format('H:i');
```

UPDATE: for dynamic start time, when the hour is not x3

```php
<?php

# The alternative start time
// $start = new DateTime('2022-12-18 13:00:00');
$start = new DateTime('2022-12-18 15:00:00');

// Moving magic number out of the calculations
$period_hours = 3;

// This is just for test, in the below code
// should be replaced with plain `(new DateTime)`
$now = new DateTime('2022-12-18 19:29:00');

// Set the next fraction-period hour
$result = ( new DateTime )
    ->setTime(
        // Divide current hour by the period, take integer part,
        // add one, multiply by period, add start DT shift,
        // and at last take 24 modulo 
        // (to get '0' instead of '24', '3' instead of '27' etc)
        (
            (((int)($now->format('H') / $period_hours) + 1 ) * $period_hours) 
            + $start->format('H') % $period_hours
        )
        % 24,
        0
    );

// The result
// Note, the day is current here
print $result->format('H:i');
```

Comment: You need to account for the start time of the period. Right now it is pure coincidence that it is "every 3 hours from this hour that _happens to be a multiple of 3_". This will also break when the period spans a DST change.

Comment: I've asked OP of what he needs as an output, read comments above. Only the hour is needed, no date, no TZ changes, no DST change involved here. And no coincidence there, your solution uses pretty much just the same mechanics. But it went messy and overcharged to support features no one needs here. Basically the question is "what is the next integer that's modulo 3 is zero", thats it.

Comment: "what is the next integer that's modulo 3 is zero" yes, but you need to account for the _start_ time of the set of periods. It the hours that the periods start on is `14` instead of `15` your code does not account for the offset and will return wrong results. Which goes double for DST changes because the hour will move out of alignment, but also that now you have awkward transition periods that are 2 or 4 hours long depending if it's spring or fall.

Comment: It's unclear if OP has his start hour other than multiple 3. His input data has an hour that's modulo 3 is zero. Well, fine, that's fixed easily. And about DST - it is absolutely unclear if this is needed. If this is some automated periodic event that must be run every N hours, yeah we gotta keep DST change in mind. While if it is some sort of shedule where the events happens every day at 15:00 (18:00, etc), we need to throw that DST change away, or we're getting one hour shifted output. Since OP said nothing about DST, i presume the last.

Comment: The fact remains that your code is fragile and filled with assumptions and you'd rather argue that "it's probably fine" than actually address them.

Comment: Who said its a fact? And i'm not sure where did u even see the dispute here. I've just stated the real facts you obviously missing. SO answer is not supposed to contain production-ready code. It is supposed to provide a general idea. This code is short, easy to understand and easy to modify. No redundant functions/variables, no unnecessary fuss. And after all no implicit transformations, containing possible bug that might take hours to debug in six months when it will fire.

Answer (score -1):

The following will properly take into account the start time and return an object with the same timezone and other properties as its input.

```php
function intervalToSeconds(DateInterval $interval) {
    $d1 = new DateTimeImmutable('', new DateTimezone('UTC'));
    $d2 = $d1->add($interval);
    return $d2->getTimestamp() - $d1->getTimestamp();
}

function getNextDateTime(DateTime $target, DateTime $start, DateInterval $interval) {
    $t_start    = $start->getTimestamp();
    $t_target   = $target->getTimestamp();
    $t_since    = $t_target - $t_start;
    $t_interval = intervalToSeconds($interval);
    
    $t_next = ( intdiv($t_since, $t_interval) + 1 ) * $t_interval + $t_start;
    
    return (clone $target)->setTimestamp($t_next);
}

$start = new DateTime('2022-12-18 16:00:00', new DateTimezone('UTC'));
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('3 hours');
$now = new DateTime('2022-12-20 23:45:01', new DateTimezone('America/Vancouver'));

var_dump(
    $start, $interval,
    getNextDateTime($now, $start, $interval)
);
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2022-12-18 16:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
object(DateInterval)#2 (2) {
  ["from_string"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["date_string"]=>
  string(7) "3 hours"
}
object(DateTime)#5 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2022-12-21 02:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(17) "America/Vancouver"
}
```